# How to disable @PreAuthorize annotation that is set on method level, in case I permit all requests globally on given end point?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // @formatter:off
    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

And this controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/test")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String helloTest(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println(principal.toString());
        return "Hello test world!";
    }
}
```

Both controller methods have a `@PreAuthorize` annotation. In security configuration I require the `/api/test/**` endpoints to be secured, while the rest should be available as anonymous.

However when I test given controller, while opening `http://localhost:8080` I get `401 Unauthorized` because of the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` annotation while I want it unsecured (`.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`).

TL:DR - I want the "global" configuration overwrite the `@PreAuthorize()` annotation.

Why? Because I want to set the `.antMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated()` part from the `application.properties` file so it can happen that if I change the value to "/api/test/hello/**" then I want the `helloTest` method be available for anonymous users without going through all the controllers and removing the `@PreAuthorize()` annotation everywhere and hope that I found it all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just disable method security then. However I see great issues with this, the URL based is more or less coarse grained security, whereas the annotation one is fine grained and should be used to fine-tune the rules. You only want the coarse grained rules then disable the method security and do everything with patterns only.

Comment: If you remove the PreAuthorize annotation from the hello method, then it will permit all requests without requiring the user to have ROLE_USER privileges. Is there a reason that the annotation needs to remain there?

Comment: disabling security for testing purposes defeats the purpose of security. How can you ensure that security works in production if you have disabled it during testing?

Comment: Are there any updates on this?